# How to inject jquery sharepoint services to spfx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

We are trying to inject [jquery sharepoint services](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) dependency to our sharepoint framework webpart.

This is what we did. First added external files at config.json

```
"externals": {
  "jQuery": {
    //"path": "/src/webparts/profileService/scripts/jquery.js",
    "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js",
    "globalName": "jQuery"
  },
  "SPServices": {
    //"path": "/src/webparts/profileService/scripts/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js",
    "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js",
    "globalName": "SPServices"
    ,"globalDependencies": ["jQuery"] //["jQuery"]
  }
},
```

Secondly at webpart we imported it

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
require('jQuery');
require('SPServices');
```

Then made the call,

```
//let services = (<any>jQuery()).SPServices;
let services = (<any>$()).SPServices;
console.dir(services);
```

That returned with undefined. In addition to that console threw another error.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error:
>       ***Failed to load path dependency "SPServices" from component "xxx" (MyWebPart).

We thought maybe loading jQuery twice was causing the error. So we tried without using the `import * as $ from 'jquery';` like this

```
const jq = require('jQuery');
require('SPServices');
```

And

```
const sps = jq.SPServices;
console.log(sps);
```

This also yields the same result. That's we got the aforementioned error at console.

What are we doing wrong?

> Versions of JavaScript Libraries used
>   jquery: 1.11.3
>   jquery.SPServices: 2014.02
>   @microsoft/spfx: 5.6.0

---

My bad, if we use `const sps = jq().SPServices;` I get the object. But the error persists,

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your `config.json` file to use the globalName property of `jQuery`. The global variable name, specified by using the globalName property, is the name known to other scripts such as plug-ins built on top of the library.

It should be as below:

```
"externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    },
    "SPServices": {
      "path": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery",
      "globalDependencies": [ "jquery" ]
    }
  },
```

After that, you should modify your import statements as below in your React component (.tsx) file or your webpart typescript file (.ts) :

```
import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
// other import statements
const $: any = require("jquery");
require('SPServices');
```

Now, in your render method you will be able to use it as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Alerts",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          console.log(xData);
          $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr("ows_Title"))            
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

Reference - [Use existing JavaScript libraries in SharePoint Framework client-side web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries#javascript-libraries-formats)